# kernel boot takes too long, probably asus makro key usb keyboard related

Tags: boot, usb, kernel, keyboard

I would like to solve my long boot issue.

```
3.19.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 31 15:52:51 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I think it might be related to ASUS ASUS ROG Macrokey keyboard which I cannot unplug (since it is built in the laptop) and appears to be connected onver USB..

Here is why I think it comes from this keyboard..
portion of dmesg where the boot time jumps from 2. to 22 in just few steps..

```
[    2.472146] input: ASUS ASUS ROG Macrokey as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/0003:0B05:17FD.0004/input/input16
[    2.524776] hid-generic 0003:0B05:17FD.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [ASUS ASUS ROG Macrokey] on usb-0000:00:14.0-10/input0
[    2.529800] hid (null): usage index exceeded
[    2.530002] hid-generic 0003:0B05:17FD.0005: usage index exceeded
[    2.530005] hid-generic 0003:0B05:17FD.0005: item 0 2 2 2 parsing failed
[    2.530013] hid-generic: probe of 0003:0B05:17FD.0005 failed with error -22
[    2.836897] Switched to clocksource tsc
[   15.504735] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   22.540974] hid-generic 0003:0B05:17FD.0006: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -1
[   22.540986] hid-generic 0003:0B05:17FD.0006: timeout initializing reports
[   22.541201] hid-generic 0003:0B05:17FD.0006: hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Device [ASUS ASUS ROG Macrokey] on usb-0000:00:14.0-10/input2
```

..it could be also the random, but there is IMHO no reason to it..

thanks